# pyspark dataframe with json column to aggregate the json elements into a new column and remove duplicated

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a pyspark dataframe with json column on databricks.

The dataframe:

```
  year month json_col
  2010 09    [{"p_id":"vfdvtbe"}, {"p_id":"cdscs"}, {"p_id":"usdvwq"}]
  2010 09    [{"p_id":"ujhbe"}, {"p_id":"cdscs"}, {"p_id":"yjev"}]
  2007 10    [{"p_id":"ukerge"}, {"p_id":"ikrtw"}, {"p_id":"ikwca"}]
  2007 10    [{"p_id":"unvwq"}, {"p_id":"cqwcq"}, {"p_id":"ikwca"}]
```

I need a new dataframe with all duplicated "p_id" are removed and aggregated by year and month

```
  year month p_id (string)
  2010 09    ["vfdvtbe", "cdscs", "usdvwq", "ujhbe", "yjev"]
  2007 10    ["ukerge", "ikrtw", "ikwca", "unvwq", "cqwcq"]
```

the new column "p_id" is a string of array.
I would like to count what distinct "p_id"s are and how many of them in each year and month.
And, also remove the duplicated elements that appear in the same year and month.

My code :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = ArrayType(StructType(
[
   StructField('p_id', StringType(), True)
]
))

schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),StringType()))

t = ff.withColumn("data",F.explode(F.from_json(F.col("json_col"),schema))).withColumn("data",F.when(F.col("data")["product_id"].cast("string").isNotNull(),F.col("data")["product_id"])).filter(F.col("data").isNotNull()).drop("json_col")


display(t)
```

I am not sure this can remove duplicates ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`flatten, array_distinct`** with **`groupBy, collect_list`**  functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|year|month|json_col                                                 |
#+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|2010|09   |[{"p_id":"vfdvtbe"}, {"p_id":"cdscs"}, {"p_id":"usdvwq"}]|
#|2010|09   |[{"p_id":"ujhbe"}, {"p_id":"cdscs"}, {"p_id":"yjev"}]    |
#|2007|10   |[{"p_id":"ukerge"}, {"p_id":"ikrtw"}, {"p_id":"ikwca"}]  |
#|2007|10   |[{"p_id":"unvwq"}, {"p_id":"cqwcq"}, {"p_id":"ikwca"}]   |
#+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = ArrayType(StructType(
[
   StructField('p_id', StringType(), True)
]
))


df1=df.withColumn("ff",from_json(col("json_col"),schema)).\
select("year","month",expr('transform(ff , f -> f.p_id)').alias("tmp"))

df1.groupBy("year","month").\
agg(to_json(array_distinct(flatten(collect_list(col("tmp"))))).alias("p_id")).\
show(10,False)
#+----+-----+-------------------------------------------+
#|year|month|p_id                                       |
#+----+-----+-------------------------------------------+
#|2010|09   |["vfdvtbe","cdscs","usdvwq","ujhbe","yjev"]|
#|2007|10   |["ukerge","ikrtw","ikwca","unvwq","cqwcq"] |
#+----+-----+-------------------------------------------+
```