# pyspark dataframe json column decompose

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to decompose a json column in pyspark dataframe.

It is similar as the question at [pyspark dataframe with json column to aggregate the json elements into a new column and remove duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220964/pyspark-dataframe-with-json-column-to-aggregate-the-json-elements-into-a-new-col)

but this new json column has more complicated structures.

The dataframe

```
 year month id json_col
 2010  08   5  {"my_p": [{"like": false, "p_id": "dfvefvsd"}, {"like": true, "p_id": "dvcdc"}], "p_id": "cdscas"}
```

I need a new col as :

```
year month id like  p_id
2010  8    5  false dfvefvsd
2010  8    5  true  dvcdc
2010  8    5  null  cdscas
```

If there are duplicated p_id in the same year,month, id, remove it.

The code learned from the above link (credit to @Shu)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

t = spark.sql('select * from my_db.my_tab')

schema = ArrayType(
                StructType(
                  [
                    StructField('my_p', 
                                        StructType(
                                                  [StructField('p_id', StringType(), True),
                                                  StructField('like', BooleanType(), True)
                                                  ]
                                        ),
                               True), 
                   StructField('p_id', StringType(), True)
                  ]
                  
                )
            )

   t1 = t.withColumn('a_col', F.from_json('json_col', schema)).select('year', 'month', 'id', 'p_id', F.expr('transform(json_col, f -> f.p_id)').alias('tmp'))

   t1.groupBy("year","month", 'id', 'p_id').agg(F.to_json(F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.collect_list(F.col("tmp"))))).alias("new_col")).show(10,False)
```

But, only the first "p_id" is decomposed from the json_col.

thanks

Comment: Can you post reproducible input dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
t.show()

#+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|year|month|id |json_col                                                                                          |
#+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|2010|08   |5  |{"my_p": [{"like": false, "p_id": "dfvefvsd"}, {"like": true, "p_id": "dvcdc"}], "p_id": "cdscas"}|
#+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

schema1='struct<my_p:array<struct<like:boolean,p_id:string>>,p_id:string>'

w=Window().partitionBy("p_id2").orderBy(F.lit(0))


t.withColumn("json_col", F.from_json("json_col",schema1))\
  .select("*","json_col.*").drop("json_col")\
  .withColumnRenamed("p_id","p_id2").select("*",F.expr("""inline(my_p)""")).drop("my_p")\
  .withColumn('num', F.row_number().over(w)).withColumn("p_id", F.when(F.col("num")==1, F.array("p_id2","p_id"))\
                                                                .otherwise(F.array("p_id"))).drop("num","p_id2")\
  .withColumn("p_id", F.explode("p_id")).show()

#+----+-----+---+-----+--------+
#|year|month| id| like|    p_id|
#+----+-----+---+-----+--------+
#|2010|   08|  5| true|   dvcdc|
#|2010|   08|  5|false|dfvefvsd|
#|2010|   08|  5|false|  cdscas|
#+----+-----+---+-----+--------+
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Is it possible to mark the value of "like" for "p_id2" as "null"? The last "p_id" in the json column is "unknown" for "like" so we prefer to mark it as "null", thanks !